# Cancel all asynchronous tasks in componentWillUnmount method react-native

Tags: react-native

Here is my code and I use asyncstorage to set user's name. I get this error

I get a warning saying Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. it indicates a memory leak. cancel and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

```
UNSAFE_componentWillMount(){ 
 this.getName()
 this.disableSEND()
}
getName = async () => {
    let value = 'userName'
    try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('NAME', value))

    } catch (e) {
        Alert.alert(e.message)
    }
}

disableSEND = async () => {
    let value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('SENDDISABLED')
    this.setState({ switch: value == 'true' ? true : false })
    let disableBtn = AsyncStorage.getItem('DISABLEBTN')
    this.setState({ disableBtn: disableBtn == 'false' ? false : true })
}
disableMSG = async (value) => {
    try {
        AsyncStorage.setItem('DISABLEMSG', value.toString())
    } catch (e) {
        Alert.alert(e.message)
    }
}

disableBtn = async (disableBtn) => {
    try {
        AsyncStorage.setItem('DISABLEBTN', disableBtn.toString())

    } catch (e) {
        Alert.alert(e.message)
    }
}
render() {
    return (
        <DrawerContentScrollView {...this.props}>

        </DrawerContentScrollView>
    );
}
```

}
})

Comment: what is the question?
PS you better youse componentDidMount over the deprecated UNSAFE_componentWillMount()

Comment: Oh I will give it a try. I updated the question.

Comment: can you share more of the component? I find it hard to believe that the AsyncStorage is causing this problem

Comment: I wonder. if you omit all code related to asyncStorage in this component. will the warning still appear?
Nothing here indicated the unmounting of a component. Basically the message says that you are trying to change state of an unmounted component. It is usually related to times/subscriptions not handled correctly or in your code you are setting a state of a component after another component unmounted this one (by callback)